# How do i fetch all the values of for loop which need to be separate and need to make a total of separated values

Tags: selenium

I am automating scraping data from a popup contain 542 values such as 12/34, 45/76, 97/23 and so on.

I am trying to print those values on console, then separating and have to display the total of the value before "/" and after "/" such as 12+457+97  and 34+76+23.

My following code is executing and prints the first 10 values, but encounters an error:

```
"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1".
```

The value of `listOfActualValues.size()` is showing correct value i.e. 542.
And the below code is to fetch the values from one column, remaining 3 columns are working fine without scrolling down and printing all 542 values.

```
int sum1=0; int sum2=0; int value1 = 0; int value2 = 0; int finalsum1=0; int finalsum2=0;
for(int av=va+1; av<listOfActualValues.size(); av++)

             { 
                System.out.format("%25s",listOfActualValues.get(av).getText());

                String str1 = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText().split("/")[1];
                String str2 = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText().split("/")[0];
                      value1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
                      value2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
                 }
         sum1 =sum1+value1;
         sum2 = sum2+value2;
         finalsum1 = sum1;
         finalsum2 = sum2;

         }
         System.out.println(finalsum1);
         System.out.println(finalsum2);
```

When I am running same code for another popup which having only 4 values in a single column, its running absolutely correct. Do I need to scroll down using Javascript.

`//div[3]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[contains(text(), '' )][3]`, it's tag giving me 542 elements td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="2"> 1667/3818

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the page you are automating, it's hard to tell what the solution needs to be here. But, you mentioned you might need to scroll down with Javascript. First, here's a method for a **generic** scroll down -- this just scrolls down using the window size as parameter. You can adjust the numbers to customize your function if need be:

```
// declare JS executor
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// scroll down using JS and window size -- this scrolls down 250 pixels
executor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

If you want a more specific scrolling method, such as one that scrolls down to a particular element, the syntax changes a bit:

```
// declare JS executor
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// this is the element you want to scroll down to
WebElement myWebElement = driver.findElement(someLocatorHere);

// scroll down using JS -- this scrolls down to the web element you pass in
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", myWebElement);
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: just need to print the values as 12/34 in next line 45/76 and so on. Basically its printing all values in a single column. But printing till 10 values only and then it gives an error. Thanks, what all you suggested above tried but same error.

Comment: I'm not sure why your code isn't working, because I can't see what is on the web page -- posting the HTML will help. Your for loop also doesn't compile, because there are missing brackets (and I am assuming, also missing pieces of the loop). It looks like the `[0]` or `[1]` index accessors are throwing the error. Maybe `listOfActualValues.get(av).getText()` returns an item that doesn't have a `/` character in it, so the access to `String str1 = listOfActualValues.get(av).getText().split("/")[1]` is throwing the error.

Comment: DIfficult to post html code and just confirmed with "/" it is there in all 542 values and its giving first 10 values which are correct. And same code has been used for next popup which having only 4 values and its running fine. And yes the other 3 columns are printing all 542 values without scroll down.

Comment: Based on this description....it works for some inputs, doesn't work for other inputs, works for first 10 values, then fails, etc, it's really impossible to solve without any additional context like the page HTML or a complete code sample.

Comment: //div[3]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[contains(text(), '' )][3] this line giving me 542 elements(td).    And each td contain some value  <td style="width: 100px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; text-align:center;" xpath="2">
1667/3818
</td> And fetching values 1667/3818...

Comment: If you want to post the HTML you testing, it would be best to edit your question and provide that information, instead of commenting here -- this will help other users (besides me) read your HTML.